# Compile code in a textbox and save to exe

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, compilation, exe

Is it possible to compile any given C# code in textbox, and then save it to an exe?

Is this possible? If so, how can it be done?

Comment: Have you done any research on this topic yourself?  If so, what have you found?

Comment: Yes i have, i have found just Runtime compiling, but none with the save.

Comment: Have you had a look here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9019/Compiling-and-Executing-Code-at-Runtime

Comment: [SO] frowns on questions that just ask a question without showing any effort to solve it on your own.  I would edit your question to include links to online resources you have found, and ask specific questions rather than just "Is it possible?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You could use [CodeDOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx). And here's [an example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lukeh/archive/2007/07/11/c-3-0-and-codedom.aspx):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var csc = new CSharpCodeProvider(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "CompilerVersion", "v3.5" } });
        var parameters = new CompilerParameters(new[] { "mscorlib.dll", "System.Core.dll" }, "foo.exe", true);
        parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
        CompilerResults results = csc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters,
        @"using System.Linq;
            class Program {
              public static void Main(string[] args) {
                var q = from i in Enumerable.Rnge(1,100)
                          where i % 2 == 0
                          select i;
              }
            }");
        results.Errors.Cast<CompilerError>().ToList().ForEach(error => Console.WriteLine(error.ErrorText));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from compiling the code at runtime, you can just save the code from your textbox to disk, and then use `csc.exe` to compile it. The command would look similar to the following:

```
%systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc /out:filename.exe filename.cs
```